# How to get rhythmbox playlist to play correctly via Rockbox on sansa clip plus?

Tags: music, rhythmbox

So I have a 128GB micro SD card on my Sansa Clip Plus running Rockbox.  When I create an m3u playlist via Rhythmbox, it does not work.  The main problem is that the playlist references absolute paths on my hard drive such as

```
home/tina/Music/iTunes/George Strait/Troubadour/I Saw God Today.mp3
```

when it should reference relative paths on the sd card such as

```
Music/George Strait/Troubadour/I Saw God Today.mp3
```

I can't do a string substitution via a text editor in the original playlist file because the paths can all be different (on my hard drive).  That's why I'm wondering if there's an automated way to do sync this via Rhythmbox?

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an *extremely* old question, but I thought that I would answer it as it is the top result on Google.

First, you need a file in the root directory of your media player so that Rhythmbox knows that it isn't just a USB mass storage device. This pertains to all media players.

1. Open your player's root directory (Just clicking on it in the file manager it should say something like "128 GB Removable Media")
2. Right click to create an empty text file. Name it `.is_audio_player`
3. Now in Rhythmbox, drag media into your playlist **from the player**, not from your computer. Doing this in combination with creating the said file should fix this issue.

Also, you may need to set some parameters in the `.is_audio_player` file to ensure Rhythmbox scans your media correctly. https://wiki.gnome.org/Attic/Banshee/CommonQuestions/IsAudioPlayerFile